# $A$ is a 3×3 matrix with eigenvalues 0,3,6 and corresponding eigenvectors $u$,$v$,$w$.

Tags: linear-algebra

How many solutions does the linear system Ax = u have?
How many solutions does the linear system Ax = 3v + 6w have?

I believe Ax = u has exactly one solution but I am not sure about Ax = 3v + 6w

Comment: If $A = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 &6\end{pmatrix}$, $u=(1,0,0)$, then $Ax=u$ has no solution.

Comment: And so, $v$ = (0,1,0) and $w$ = (0,0,1). This means that Ax = 3v + 6w has one solution to confirm my initial belief, correct?

Comment: No. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since $u,v,w$ correspond to different eigenvalues, they are linearly independent, and hence form a basis for $\mathbb{R^3}$.
If
$$ A(au+bv+cw)=u $$
or, equivalently,
$$ a0 + 3bv + 6cw = u \mbox{,}$$
then $u,v,w$ are linearly dependent, a contradiction. Thus, $Ax=u$ has no solution.

I think you are able to solve the other question yourself now.